# onKeyDown event not working on divs in React

Tags: reactjs, events, keypress, keydown

I want to use a keyDown event on a div in React. I do:

```
  componentWillMount() {
      document.addEventListener("keydown", this.onKeyPressed.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.onKeyPressed.bind(this));
  }      
  
  onKeyPressed(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
  }
    
  render() {
    let player = this.props.boards.dungeons[this.props.boards.currentBoard].player;
    return (
      <div 
        className="player"
        style={{ position: "absolute" }}
        onKeyDown={this.onKeyPressed} // not working
      >
        <div className="light-circle">
          <div className="image-wrapper">
            <img src={IMG_URL+player.img} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

It works fine, but I would like to do it more in React style. I tried

```
onKeyDown={this.onKeyPressed}
```

on the component. But it doesn't react. It works on input elements as I recall.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/lafisrap/pen/OmyBYG)

How can I do it?

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/event-listeners-in-react-components

Answer (score 268, accepted):

You should use **tabIndex** attribute to be able to listen `onKeyDown` event on a div in React. Setting `tabIndex="0"` should fire your handler.

Comment: This seems like bad, opinionated design.  What if I want to handle a bubbling event on a container element but that container itself should not ever be focused?

Comment: This seems like more of a hack or workaround to me. There may be a time when you need to have the given div maintain a tab order.

Comment: `tabIndex={-1}` can also be used if you're working with an element that isn't interactive and don't want to change the tab order of the document.

Comment: you have to set the tabIndex, to make the div focusable. You can set the tabIndex to 0,1,-1.... But before you do that check this out 

https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex

You'll likely want to set to -1 since you're manipulating it programmatically.

Comment: for some reason this only works if I have an <input> element in the div with the tabIndex. Or something else that can be focussed. With just other divs, its still not capturing. Any thoughts?

Comment: adding tabIndex is not working for me, I am trying to get the value from the input and I have this code:

`<div onKeyDown={(e) => handleOnKeyDown(e)}>`

...here i have custom component that has input value..

`</div>`
Does someone know why what might be the problem?

Comment: +1 to @Muppet for removing the outline too: 

import styled from "styled-components"

const KeyReceiver = styled.div`
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`

Answer (score 37):

You need to write it this way

```
<div 
    className="player"
    style={{ position: "absolute" }}
    onKeyDown={this.onKeyPressed}
    tabIndex="0"
  >
```

If `onKeyPressed` is not bound to `this`, then try to rewrite it using arrow function or bind it in the component `constructor`.

Comment: Sorry. I was sure, I just overlooked the this. But this is not the problem. It's still not working.

Comment: updated answer. You should either click on the div or bring it to focus before pressing any keys.

Comment: I did. It's not working. I updated the code above. It works fine with the DOM commands, but not in React style.

Comment: can you explain what is not working? is your function not getting callled or `console.log` is outputing nothing ?

Comment: The function is not called. I have a codepen: http://codepen.io/lafisrap/pen/OmyBYG . It about lines 275 and 307.

Comment: works for me with tabIndex={0} , tabIndex requires a number, not a string, so tabIndex="0" was flagged as a typescript error

Answer (score 11):

You're thinking too much in pure Javascript. Get rid of your listeners on those React lifecycle methods and use `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode` (because this is not a JS event object, it is a React [SyntheticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)). Your entire component could be as simple as this (assuming you haven't bound your methods in a constructor).

```
onKeyPressed(e) {
  console.log(e.key);
}

render() {
  let player = this.props.boards.dungeons[this.props.boards.currentBoard].player;
  return (
    <div 
      className="player"
      style={{ position: "absolute" }}
      onKeyDown={this.onKeyPressed}
    >
      <div className="light-circle">
        <div className="image-wrapper">
          <img src={IMG_URL+player.img} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: That's exactly how I wanted to write it. But the hell, it's not going. Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/lafisrap/pen/OmyBYG . If you comment line 275 then key board input (cursor keys) is not working. onKeyDown is in line 307.

Comment: keyCode I use for cursor keys, as they return no character.

Comment: React doesn't use Javascript event objects, so there is no keyCode property. That `event` object is a React [SyntheticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).

Comment: @Michael I also am not entirely sure how you are triggering a key event on a div, but when I put this code into a fiddle with an `onClick` prop instead of `onKeyDown` the handler fires.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it ... The key events work in input fields though.

Answer (score 10):

Using the `div` trick with `tab_index="0"` or `tabIndex="-1"` works, but any time the user is focusing a view that's not an element, you get an ugly focus-outline on the entire website. This can be fixed by setting the CSS for the div to use `outline: none` in the focus.

Here's the implementation with styled components:

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const KeyReceiver = styled.div`
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`
```

and in the App class:

```
  render() {
    return (      
      <KeyReceiver onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress} tabIndex={-1}>
          Display stuff...
      </KeyReceiver>
    )
```

Answer (score 7):

Also, remember that this trick will only work when focus is set on your div. If you want to manage keypress as soon as the div pops up, you can use [this trick](https://codesandbox.io/s/div-keyboard-management-x30wu?file=/src/App.js:0-1020) (especially useful for Drawers/Modals)

Answer (score 5):

The answer with

```
<div 
    className="player"
    onKeyDown={this.onKeyPressed}
    tabIndex={0}
>
```

works for me, please note that the tabIndex requires a number, not a string, so tabIndex="0" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having issues with this I was losing the plot with on key down and on key up not working you can use mouse events.

This was fine for what I needed.

```
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const handleDown = () => {
    console.log('down')
  }
  const handleUp = () => {
    console.log('up')
  }
  return (
    <button onMouseDown={handleDown} onMouseUp={handleUp}>
      PRESS DOWN
    </button>
  )
}

export default App
```