# Not able to dispatch KeyDown event to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I would like to dispatch onKeyDown events from a body element too a div inside of the body.

I am using React and have tried adding an onKeyDown event listener to my body tag in the componentDidMount function of my React component.

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById("main-content").onkeydown = event => {
        document.getElementById("Keyboard").dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

I expected the keydown event to be dispatched to the Keyboard component, but instead I receive the error listed below.

InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not hardcode it onto your div element?
Use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503964/onkeydown-event-not-working-on-divs-in-react) as reference if you can.

If you can't harcode it maybe try this:

```
    document.querySelector('#yourDiv').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
      console.log(event.key) //Change this to whatever you want it to do
    })
```

Then in your HTML give your div a `tabindex="0"` property.

**The tabindex property:**

> tabindex="0" allows a non-form/link/object element to be placed in the default navigation order, allowing any element to be focusable and trigger interaction.

More info [here](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/tabindex-attribute/)

Comment: Thank you, the question you linked worked! I tried hardcoding it, but I forgot to set tabIndex="0".

Comment: Glad I could help! I fell for the same problem before