# How to add onKeyDown event for Range?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, range

I'm using for my project the Range component from here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-slider

There are 4 values marked on the range:

- the `min` value,
- a (let's say) random value in the `middle`,
- the`max` value
- the `currentlyChosenValue`.

The requirement was to introduce `steps` for this slider, so that

1. the user only sees values rounded to the nearest 10 as `currentlyChosenValue`, when he is dragging the slider,
2. the user only sees values rounded up to the nearest 10, when he pushes the left-right arrow keys.

I could not use the `step` property defined for the , as my `min`, `max` and `middle` values are pretty random (they are not rounded).
Therefore, I defined a function which rounds the values `onChange` - it works properly for point #1 (e.g. rounding to `min`, when selected value is close to `min`).

However, when the user presses the left/right arrow key, the slider tries to move one step left/right - which gets rounded back to the original value ==> slider won't move eventually. I could not find a way to define a separate `onKeyDown` event for my Range, I tried to add a `Handle` with an onKeyDown - but my function there was never triggered.

```
  import { Handle, Range } from "rc-slider";

  const handle = props => {
    const { value, ...restProps } = props;
    const change = event => {
      // was never triggered
      console.log("a key was pressed", event);
    };
    return <Handle value={value} onKeyPress={change} {...restProps} />;
  };

  <Range
    handle={handle}
    value={[min, middle, currentlyChosenValue]}
    min={min}
    max={max}
    onChange={memoizedOnChange}
  />
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `<Handle/>` is a component, you're passing `onKeyPress={change}` down as a prop.

You could wrap a div around `<Handle/>` and put `onKeyPress={change}` on that div.

Your also want to use `tabIndex="0"` as an attribute when you do this. This link talks about why:

[onKeyDown event not working on divs in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503964/onkeydown-event-not-working-on-divs-in-react?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
return (
    <div onKeyPress={change} tabIndex="0">
        <Handle value={value} {...restProps} />;
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've tried it out, and I'm not sure, why, but the change function still doesn't get triggered.. :( Besides, I get some eslint errors, if I add an Event Handler to a `div` - therefore, I'm not sure, if this would pass our code review (we also have to comply with the WCAG requirements and I suspect that this might be against it)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a div around the Range component and listen for key events there.