# Reactjs How to use properly onKeyDownCapture?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm using onWheelCapture to detect the scroll offset from the top. As I'm using onWheelCapture, it only detects the movement when the user scrolls up or down. I would like to detect the scroll offset when the user presses the key-down or space key. So I tried to use ***onKeyDownCapture*** in order to listen to when using the keyboard but it doesn't work. I also tried it with ***onKeyPressCapture*** but it doesn't work either. This was checked using the console, it only prints the distance from the top when scrolling.

```
    <React.Fragment>

    <main className={classes.Content}  
        onWheelCapture={props.onScrollMethod}   //This one works
        onKeyPressCapture={props.onScrollMethod}    //This one doesn't work
        onKeyDownCapture={props.onScrollMethod} >     //This one doesn't work either
        <div className={classes.ContentWrapper}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    </main> 
</React.Fragment>
```

Am I missing something? Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non interactive elements need to have `tabIndex` set in order to be able to listen for these events. Discussed here: [onKeyDown event not working on divs in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503964/onkeydown-event-not-working-on-divs-in-react).

Working code snippet, but you need to focus the gray div to see the events logged.

```js
function CaptureComp() {

  const keyHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.altKey,
      e.charCode,
      e.ctrlKey,
      e.key,
      e.keyCode,
      e.ctrlKeylocale,
      e.location,
      e.metaKey,
      e.repeat,
      e.shiftKey,
      e.which)  
  }

  return (
    <div className="container"
      onKeyDownCapture={keyHandler}
      onKeyPressCapture={keyHandler}
      onKeyUpCapture={keyHandler}
      tabIndex="-1"
      >
            <p>Event Container</p>
    </div> 
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<CaptureComp />, document.getElementById('App'));
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
 }
 p {
  text-align:center;
  padding:4rem;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="App"></div>
```